# Net Core - Integration test - TestServer - real http connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, integration-testing

We have several .NET Core Microservices / API and we wish to do some integration tests.
So, we have follow the tutorials and it work fine, except for one situation.

Imagine I have 3 API, so 3 "TestServer" instance, each has its own HttpClient to connect with !

I show the way I create the TestServer :

```
    private TestServer SetupAPI<TStartup>(string path, string uri) where TStartup : class
    {
        string rootPath = Path.Join(_rootPath, "path");

        var hostBuilder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseUrls(uri)
            .UseIISIntegration()
            //.ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSecurityHeaders())
            .UseContentRoot(rootPath)
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(cb =>
            {
                cb.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
                //.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .UseStartup<TStartup>();

        TestServer server = new TestServer(hostBuilder);
        server.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);

        return server;
    }
```

I show how I create the HttpClient :

```
        client = ArtistsServer.CreateClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

It works perfectly, but when I try to create a new HttpClient that way, it failed:
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");

The real problem is that some microservices create their own HttpClient that way in order to communicate with other API ! They are setup through the appsettings.json file and try to connect to a normal and real http server, not a "TestServer" one !

Do you have any idea to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score -3):

That's not how this works. An integration test is a test of the suite of components that make up a *single* app. If you're testing Api1, you don't spin up instances of Api2 and Api3; you mock those so that they behave in a known and predictable way. If you used real instances, even *test* instances, then a failure in Api2 could cause your test of Api1 to fail, even though there's nothing wrong with Api1.

So, for Api1 to communicate to Api2, you'd need an `HttpClient` to make requests with. That `HttpClient` should be provided by `IHttpClientFactory` and injected into a service class registered as a typed client. On this service class, you would add methods to correspond to API calls. For testability, this service class should implement an interface, and you should then inject the interface whenever you need to work with this API. That looks roughly like:

```
public interface IApi2Service
{
    Task<Foo> GetFooByIdAsync(int id);
}

public class Api2Service : IApi2Service
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public Api2Service(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task<Foo> GetFooByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        // use _client to make the API call
    }
}
```

Then, in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IApi2Service, Api2Service>(c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["Api2BaseAddress"]);
});
```

And finally, in the class (maybe a controller) in Api1 where you need to interact with Api2, you do:

```
public class SomeApi1Controller : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IApi2Service _api2Service;

    public SomeApi1Controller(IApi2Service api2Service)
    {
        _api2Service = api2Service;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> SomeAction()
    {
        var foo = await _api2Service.GetFooByIdAsync(1);
    }
}
```

Now, with you code properly set up, you'd then simply sub in a test implementation of `Api2Service` and stub out the `GetFooByIdAsync` method to simply return a test `Foo` instance, instead of *actually* making a call to Api2 via the `HttpClient`. That way, you know exactly what will be returned, and can design your test appropriately, returning different kinds of `Foo` instances as appropriate to what you're testing.